# How to run a command for all users in a specific group at login, any help would be appreciated

Tags: command-line, bash, startup

We are using Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 to host virtual devices in our office. Our boss has written a program for Ubuntu that logs all activity and time spent at a single workstation to monitor misusage of company assets.

He has tasked me with getting this program to for users in the `aduio` group (a group we created for receptionists and assistants).

I have tried adding the command to the end of  `.profile` (eg `#!/bin/bash confidential -host "ip" -name $USER`) the programs starts in a kiosk mode; only this program loads, there is no access to anything else as this user. When the program is started manually from the workstation it executes without a problem.

How do I delay the startup and allow the essentials to load before running this program?

Comment: I've just messed around with the English in this post to make it a bit quicker to the point and a little more structured. If you think I've broken it, let me know.

Comment: Also, I don't really understand your `#!/bin/bash confidential...` example. Sticking that halfway through `~/.profile` will break it.

Comment: What if you run it like `confidential -host "ip" -name $USER &`?

Answer (score 2):

I would keep this out of the user's homedir. That's just begging for people to hack it to bits. That part is simple enough though, you can just add a new file to `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` (eg `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90-confidential` with the content:

```
if [[ `groups | grep aduio` ]]
then
    exec confidential -host "ip" -name $USER &
fi
```

This isn't immune to being worked around. It's still running *as* the user (so they can terminate it) and they could butcher their X startup (because it's all run as the user). You probably could lock all that down but it's a big step.

Comment: Thank you Oli so much for such  quick response. I will go and try out this solution right now, and provide feed back shortly.

Comment: Thank you too Jorqe Castro for correcting my bad grammar. any help is much appreciated this has had me stumped for a while now

Comment: I have just attempted to add the file and initiate a reboot to see if the changes would produce the desired effect but I had no luck. I typed your script precisely (making necessary substitutions) and saved it with a similar name as well. Do I have to sudo chmod +x to make it executable? should I have saved the script file as a .sh or .bash? should I have began the script with #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/sh? is there anything implied that I may have missed in your description?